# Texture Paint isn't saving. Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials, texture-painting

So... I have just started working with texture paint. I save and exit blender and I come back to see that what I painted is not there anymore. And while painting, when I check the render view, the changes I made in texture paint mode aren't showing up. Can someone help with this?

Comment: You need to save the painted texture as an image. If you didn't, and closed the project, your texture is gone for good.